# Помогите разобраться с лицензиями к программам на Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, лицензирование

Так как я практически написал библиотеку и программу на бесплатной версии Qt, пришло время задуматься о лицезии.

1. С библиотекой я думаю использовать Apache License 2.0.

   > Apache даёт пользователю право использовать программное обеспечение для любых целей, свободно распространять, изменять, и распространять изменённые копии, за исключением названия"

Мне это подходит, я все выложу в открытый доступ на Git-hub, я правильно думаю?

2. Теперь о программе. Вот с программой под десктоп, которая будет бесплатной, выкладывать открытый исходный код на git-hub мне не хочется, я так понял с этого выражения

   > The Qt Company предоставляет возможность использования открытой лицензии, в рамках которой некоторые модули доступны под LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3/GPLv3, другие – только под LGPLv3.

что исходный код можно не показывать. Какую лицензию для бесплатной проги взять чтобы исходный код все же был закрыт? В принципе на крайний случай я готов выложить исходный код, если так, то надо принять GPL 3.0? Спс если кто то поможет разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По опыту использовать Qt в разных компаниях, обычно использование Qt не требует от вас выкладывать исходники, если вы используете динамическую линкову с Qt (Qt в dll). Лицензию при этом надо брать LGPL. Но вы не можете модифицировать исходники Qt. Если вы статически линкуетесь с Qt то исходный код надо вроде бы выкладывать. Можете посмотреть вот этот сайт по лицензиям: https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v3-(lgpl-3)

Тут могут быть всякие трюки например: Основаную бизнес-логику помещаете в dll и делаете её закрытой, при этом exe файл открыт и использует Qt для вывода информации.

Также я встречал OpenSource проекты, которые имели открытый исходный код, но продавали платные модули для своих программ.

Ссылка, которая может помочь в выборе под какой лицензией использовать Qt:https://www.qt.io/download-guide/

Comment: Если хотяте использоваться статику - то придётся выкладывать объектные файлы, чтобы каждый мог динамически собрать.

Comment: Спс. Наверно так и поступлю.